# Laravel unable to handle multiple http request (API request)

Tags: php, laravel, webengage

I created  SMS API by using Laravel 7.x which will execute by WebEngage.
Webengage hitting laravel api and laravel api will send sms to users.

**Webengage hitting 500-1000 request per second and Laravel accepting only 60-70 request per second**

And then I thought, Might be my server unable to accept 1000 requests per second.
Then I created a normal PHP file in which I wrote code that store logs only.

There I checked, it was able to store 49000 requests per second. But this thing is not executing in Laravel.

What should I do?

Laravel Conf:-

```
 "php": "^7.2.5",
"laravel/framework": "^7.24",
```

Comment: What kind of server hardware? What server software? Laravel is a much larger application than a single PHP file.

Comment: @yakatz I faced the problem i saw the logs. try yourself hit multiple request in laravel api then see the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the "throttle" limit of your Laravel.
By default, it's set to 60 calls / minutes, this value can be overrided in conf files or in routes/api.php file.

```
'middleware' => 'throttle:' . Config::get('app.rate_limit', 60) .',1'
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment.