# laravel 10 getting limited or blocked request API, only 5-7 request per second

Tags: php, laravel

I'm beginner in laravel, I want to create web application with laravel 10, but when I try to test hit multiple requests in laravel using Apache jmeter (100 request), it getting limit/blocking process, only 5-7 requests per second, it was so slow, but inside my controller don't have any process, it was return empty array.

I try some internet search suggestion like 'comment throttle in kernel.php', or change .env to `app_debug=false` or increase limit in `RouteServiceProvider.php`, or clear cache with `php artisan optimize:clear`, or make caching for routes and config

not affected at all, still getting limit/blocking request. I curious is there any config I need to adjust? or it was the limit laravel can do?

Reference Link:

[Disable rate limiter in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058219/disable-rate-limiter-in-laravel)

[How to set the rate limiter for per second in Laravel version 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830534/how-to-set-the-rate-limiter-for-per-second-in-laravel-version-8)

[Laravel unable to handle multiple http request (API request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232056/laravel-unable-to-handle-multiple-http-request-api-request)

- getting limit/blocked request

[image: getting limit/blocked request by laravel]

- my route in `routes/api.php`

[image]

- my controller

[image]

but when I try to serve using native php webserver from [this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) using command `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` I'm getting like this image below, this is exactly what I want.! **one second can handle multiple request**,

but in **laravel** is was getting **limit/blocked** can someone help me?

[image]

Additional Information:

Using `php artisan serve` running in my local pc

```
PHP 8.2.5 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2023 08:42:33) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.5, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Laravel Framework 10.13.5

Windows 10 64-bit, 16Gb Ram DDR4, CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, problem in runtime `serve` when using `php artisan serve`, now I'm using laravel octane with `Swoole` runtime and it running exactly what I want..

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/octane